# How do I edit part SchLib file from SchDoc file in Altium?

Tags: altium

Right now my only method to edit library files invovles searching in the Windows file explorer.  There has to be a better way to edit the part directly through Altium.

Comment: What are you trying to edit? The footprint? Please be a little more descriptive in what you are trying to do. Describe your Altium project file structure - do you have the library added to your project?

Comment: yes, I already have the schematic libraries installed.  I'm trying to edit the symbols in the installed libraries(the SchLib files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you mean is you have a schematic which contains components wired together.  One of those components needs to be modified for some reason, but there's no easy way to edit the component in the library itself without going to find it.

Firstly, you should really have your libraries installed in Altium. On the right is a button which brings up the libraries. Find the component in there and edit it.

[image: Altium Libraries]         [image: Edit component]

This will take you straight to the schematic library with the chosen component open and ready to be edited. No messing around in Explorer.

---

Alternatively, you can edit some features of the component directly within the schematic; pins names/numbers, description, footprint, etc.  The problem with doing this however is that those changes will be lost if you ever update the component from the libraries.

Double click on the component to bring up its dialog box. There you can edit a bunch of things.  In the bottom left is the 'Edit Pins' button, which lets you edit most of the pins' properties.

Comment: "But there's no easy way to edit the component in the library itself without going to find it."     ----       that answers my question.

Comment: @lyncas - Glad to help. Just know that you don't have to find it using Explorer, you can just get it in your library.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Altium Designer you can do this by opening the library as a "free document";

1. Open the library file in Altium `File > Open...`, or by navigating to the library file in Windows explorer and double-clicking it.
2. The library should open as a "free document" where you can now make edits, add new parts, etc...

[image: Altium free document]

3. After editing you will need to update any parts you already have placed but later modified (and need the modifications).